# Only allow certain values in column B based on the value of column A

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

I want to allow allow only a set number of values to be inserted into column `A`, and depending on the value entered, allow only a certain number of values to be inserted into column `B`. For example

For example

- If A = 1, B can be between 1 and 9
- If A = 2, B can be between 10 AND 19
- If A = 3, B can be between 20 AND 29

How can I achieve this?

I figured check constraints are the best place to start. A simple constraint will ensure only values 1-3 can be added to column `A`. Such as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    col_a INT, 
    col_b INT,
    CONSTRAINT ch_col_a_valid_range CHECK (col_a BETWEEN 1 AND 3)
)
GO
```

Then I fugured that using a scalar function to determine whether the `col_b` is valid, by passing in the value from `col_a` and `col_b`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.value_is_valid (
    @a INT, 
    @b INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@a = 1 AND @b BETWEEN 1 AND 9) RETURN 1;
    IF (@a = 2 AND @b BETWEEN 10 AND 19) RETURN 1;
    IF (@a = 3 AND @b BETWEEN 20 AND 29) RETURN 1;
    RETURN 0;
END
GO
```

Then add the constraint to the table, and call the function as part of the check.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    col_a INT, 
    col_b INT,
    CONSTRAINT ch_col_a_valid_range CHECK (col_a BETWEEN 1 AND 3),
    CONSTRAINT ch_col_b_valid_based_on_a CHECK(dbo.value_is_valid(col_a, col_b) = 1)
)
GO
```

However, the following insert fails, complaining about a conflict with the `ch_col_b_valid_based_on_a` constraint that was added.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.test (
    col_a, 
    col_b
)
VALUES (1, 9)
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ch_col_b_valid_based_on_a". The conflict occurred in database " MyDB", table "dbo.test".

What can I do to work around this and achieve the result mentioned above?

---

On looking back, this approach of using a scalar function in a check constraint works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    col_a INT, 
    col_b INT,
    CONSTRAINT ch_col_a_valid_range CHECK (col_a BETWEEN 1 AND 3),
    CONSTRAINT chk_col_a_colb
        CHECK ( (col_a = 1 AND col_b BETWEEN 1 AND 9) OR
                (col_a = 2 AND col_b BETWEEN 10 AND 19) OR
                (col_a = 3 AND col_b BETWEEN 20 AND 29)
             )

);
```

However, I might be inclined to created an `AB_valid` table with a list of valid pairs and use a foreign key constraint.  That way, the list of valid values could be maintained dynamically rather than requiring modification to the table definition.

Comment: The problem with the check constraint is that it doesnt work when inserting values into both `col_a` and `col_b`. The only way around this, as far as I can tell, would be to insert into `col_a` in one transaction, then insert into `col_b` in another, but this is far from ideal. I do like your ideal of holding a FK relationship to a table of *valid* options. That could work nicely

Comment: Actually, my comment is incorrect - this check constraint approach *does* work, and the example in my original comment *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some math to create a simpler constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    col_a INT, 
    col_b INT,
    CONSTRAINT ch_col_a_valid_range CHECK (col_a BETWEEN 1 AND 3),
    CONSTRAINT ch_col_b_valid_based_on_a CHECK(col_b/10 + 1 = col_a)
);
```